# Mobile Automation with Appium, WebdriverIO using Typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, mobile, automation, webdriver-io

I'm a beginner in test automation and i want to know if there is any good support, tutorials anything that i can start with.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Did you try Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html)

[Medium article](https://itnext.io/mobile-automation-with-appium-webdriverio-using-typescript-bbb7e982b6ea)

[Boilplate](https://github.com/igniteram/appium-webdriverio-typescript)

and of course Google with keywords "Typescript Appium WDIO"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already find the same tutorial with those keywords cause it's is the only useful one.